# Fast implement wrapping (delegate methods) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, wrapper, code-assist, code-templates

Is there some template or something to implement iterface methods with accessing to wrapped member?

For example, suppose I have

```
public class MyClass implements List<Something> {

    private final List<Something> core;

...
}
```

and now I want to implement `List<Something>` by passing calls to wrapped like

```
@Override
public int size() {
    return core.size();
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is.  Use Source menu->Generate Delegate Methods...

Answer (score 9):

I'll say a bit more about how the "Generate Delegate Methods" refactoring works to create a forwarding class like you describe.

You make a new class which optionally implements the interface, and provide it with a field with the type you want to delgate, e.g.:

```
public class NewClass implements ThatInterface {
  private final ThatInterface delegate;

  public MyClass(ThatInterface delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate();
  }
}
```

*Then* you apply the eclipse refactoring.  (Cmd-3 deleg... is an easy way to access it.)  Select the checkbox for the new field.  All of its methods will be added as delegates.

*(There is a bug, I think, in the refactoring for Eclipse oxygen, where it will copy the `default` keyword from methods with that keyword on the interface.  You may need to delete that keyword.)*

So for a delegate to a List the refactoring produced:

```
public class NewClass {
   private final List<String> delegate;

   public NewClass(List<String> delegate) {
       this.delegate = delegate;
   }


   public void forEach(Consumer<? super String> action) {
       delegate.forEach(action);
   }
   public int size() {
       return delegate.size();
   }
   public boolean isEmpty() {
       return delegate.isEmpty();
   }
   public boolean contains(Object o) {
       return delegate.contains(o);
   }
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Tested in Luna.

Use shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> 2 times.  Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>