# Java Multiple Inheritance without Source Code

Tags: java, interface, multiple-inheritance, extend

I have a class called `Thing` and a class called `Robot`. `Thing` has a public void `setBlocksExit()`. `Robot` has some methods I also desire.

I have extended `Robot` but I also want `setBlocksExit()` from `Thing`. I would make an interface that has `setBlocksExit()` and then make a class like:

```
public class C extends Robot implements BlockExit {}
```

The problem is I don't have access to the source code for `Thing` and `Robot`. I am using an educational package *'becker.jar'* and all of the code is compiled so I can't access it to extract interfaces. What are my options?

Comment: Does Robot extend Thing?

Comment: @immibis No, it doesn't unfortunately. It's outrageous not to include source code in an educational package. Ah well...

Comment: 1) You don't need the source code to 'extract' or use interfaces 2) There are library / class / JAR browsers 3) Java can be decompiled if you really want

Comment: Use an Adapter Pattern.

Comment: Why do you need source code, just extend it and you have full access to modify (almost) anything.

Comment: Do you need C to extend Robot? As you describe it, looks like your are subclassing Robot just for convenience, so you can easily access its methods. Could you include both Robot and Thing instead of subclassing any of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are the following:

- Extend `Thing` and have a reference to a `Robot` which you delegate all `Robot` methods to.
- Extend `Robot` and have a reference to a `Thing` object which you delegate `setBlocksExit` calls to.
- Create a fresh class and have a reference to a `Robot` and a reference to a `Thing` and delegate calls to these two objects.

If you're using an IDE such as Eclipse you can even "extract interfaces" and generate delegate methods automatically.

Option 1:

```
class C extends Thing {
    final Robot robot;
    public C(Robot robot) {
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    public int robotMethod1() {
        return robot.robotMethod1();
    }

    ...
}
```

Option 2:

```
class C extends Robot {
    final Thing thing;
    public C(Thing thing) {
        this.thing = thing;
    }

    public void setBlocksExit(boolean flag) {
        return thing.setBlocksExit(flag);
    }

    ...
}
```

Option 3:

```
class C {
    final Thing thing;
    final Robot robot;
    public C(Thing thing, Robot robot) {
        this.thing = thing;
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    public void setBlocksExit(boolean flag) {
        return thing.setBlocksExit(flag);
    }

    public int robotMethod1() {
        return robot.robotMethod1();
    }
    ...
}
```

If you're using Eclipse you could use this feature:

- [Fast implement wrapping (delegate methods) in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397108/fast-implement-wrapping-delegate-methods-in-eclipse)

I'm sure whatever IDE you're using has a similar feature.

Comment: This seems like a decent solution although I am not quite comprehending it. Could you please show me in code?

Comment: Quick question, what does 'flag' mean or is it just a placeholder name? if the method requires 4 arguments would I pass 4 placeholder names?

Also, how are you returning  in a void method?

Comment: Yes. `flag` is just a generic name for a boolean variable :-) You can probably come up with better names.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative would be to wrap `Robot` and `Thing` in your own wrapper classes

```
public class MyRobot extends Robot implements IBlockingObject
```

and

```
public class MyThing extends Thing implements IBlockingObject
```

where you can force the interface

```
interface IBlockingObject{
   void setBlocksExit(boolean blocksExit);
}
```

Then you can use `IBlockingObject` reliably elsewhere in your code, without much overhead.

Another alternative would be to compose a class with both `Robot` and `Thing` as member fields

Something like

```
public class RobotThing extends IBlockingObject{
  // This is now a robot thing...
  private Robot mRobot;
  private Thing mThing;

  @Override 
  public void setBlocksExit(boolean blocksExit){ 
    mRobot.setBlocksExit(blocksExit);
    mThing.setBlocksExit(blocksExit);
  }
}
```

I assume the first would be more flexible for you in the long run.