# Strategy for Wrapping external library return types

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, refactoring, tdd

I have been asked to *unit test* some legacy code.

Currently, the code is tightly coupled with a *3rd party library* both in terms of method calls and types used.

I am planning on writing a *wrapper around the library* in the form of a *Façade design pattern* which will aid in testability, create a cleaner interface for the rest of the code and allow me to swap out the library in the future if required.

This works fine where the method calls are *void return type* because the library functions are self contained. But what if the existing code uses library specific types? An example is here:

```
LibrarySpecificType[] myVar = wrappedLibrary.DoX();
```

Although I have wrapped my library call in the above example, it still returns a library specific type, so it is still somewhat coupled.

Does anybody know a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just create wrapper classes around the types that are returned and have the `wrappedLibrary` return those wrapped types instead. This might be quite a lot of work if each of those types also exposes methods which accept and return other types. Something like this:

```
WrappedLibrarySpecificType[] myVar = wrappedLibrary.DoX();
```

Then in the library wrapper will have to call the actual library and wrap the type the library returns and return the wrapped type.

This ends up being a rabbit hole though and you will probably need to wrap every type.

If this is a large library you might find some benefit in writing (or using) a tool which will be able to generate the wrappers for you by reflecting over the types in the third-party library

you might have some assistance in [generating the delegating members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397108/fast-implement-wrapping-delegate-methods-in-eclipse), depending on your ide