# Is there any way to "extend" or make a shortcut to a Java wrapper class' wrapped member's methods?

Tags: java, methods, wrapper

I have a wrapper class and an object it is wrapping. I want to call `wrapper.method()` and have it equate to `object.method()` without explicitly defining it for wrapper.

Is this possible?

Because otherwise you have to copy and paste every single of object's methods because Java is all about encapsulation and making the object public would make rivers run red.

Comment: You mean that you want to avoid explicitly writing delegating method calls? Just get your IDE to generate them, e.g. [in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397108/fast-implement-wrapping-delegate-methods-in-eclipse).

Comment: Sounds like a task where [aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) might be useful.

Comment: ++ide generation.  In Netbeans, press alt-insert when the keyboard focus is inside the wrapper class, but not inside any of its methods, or right-click in such a place and select "Insert Code", then choose "Delegate method" - you can select multiple methods to delegate simultaneously.

Comment: Without the fine NetBeans IDE you could first extend the class wíth that of the field, in the IDE do "override all methods" and then replace "super." with "field.".

Comment: Use a `Proxy` instead?

Comment: @AndyTurner Perfect! I never actually knew what delegate methods meant... It still kind of clutters up the class with a lot of functions but oh well, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapper.getObject().method() call?? This should resolve your problem of copy-paste.

Edit after comment:
Yup! It would defile the purpose of wrapping.

Comment: That would defile wrapping the object in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in pure java, but you can achieve this with Lombok. See [@Delegate](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate.html). Note that the feature is marked as "experimental", so to be used with caution.